# Как сделать копирование record с массивом в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, record

Есть вот такой record с массивом:

```
  TMyVertex2Array = array of TMyVertex2; // Объявление типа массива

  TMyPolygon = record
    Points: TMyVertex2Array;
    class function New(aX1, aY1, aX2, aY2, aX3, aY3: Single): TMyPolygon; static;
    // ... и еще куча полезных методов и операторов
    procedure Offset(aX, aY: Single);
  end;
```

Далее в коде происходит примерно следующее:

```
var
  a, b: TMyPolygon;
begin
  a := TMyPolygon.New(0,0,1,1,2,2);
  b := a;
  b.Offset(10, 10);

  Assert(a.Points[0].X = 0); // <<-- Ошибка, т.к. изменился и массив а.Points
```

То есть технически, Делфа копирует record, но т.к. массив это всего лишь указатель, то копируется указатель, а сам массив остается тот же (общий для двух record).

Как, используя новые возможности Delphi, правильно скопировать record с массивом при присвоении (`b := a`), чтобы массив `Points` тоже скопировался? (т.н. глубокое копирование) или же решить проблему другим способом?

Comment: кстати, почему `static new`, а не конструктор?

Comment: да еще с 2009й версии, емнип, появились конструкторы у записей. вместе с процедурами/функциями

Comment: @teran в давние времена вот с этим согласился и всегда для record использую New (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42119979/77764). Если запостите вопрос/ответ в чем существенная разница и плюсы минусы вариантов с конструктором или статик нью, то накину +75 репы.

Comment: дак и нет разницы. но точка зрения, что конструктор в записях вносит некоторые непонятки и может запутать разработчика имеет место быть, т.к. не всегда сразу ясно, где класс, а где запись. Использовать это в коде, или нет тут дело каждого. В самих делфях - используется. К примеру  тот же `TRttiContext.Create`.  я и не настаиваю на использовании, просто на глаза попалось.

Comment: Вообще есть [интересная статья](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2015/01/implementing-record-assignment-operator_9.html) на эту тему, если я всё правильно понял :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Альтернативный вариант - сделать редизайн record и явно выделить два метода с соответствующими поведениями (изменение и создание глубокой копии):

```
  TMyPolygon = record
    Points: TMyVertex2Array;
    procedure Offset(aX, aY: Single); // Изменяет текущий record
    function GetOffset(aX, aY: Single): TMyPolygon; // Отдает новый record
  end;
```

А код сделать вот таким:

```
a := TMyPolygon.New(0,0,1,1,2,2);
b := a.GetOffset(10, 10);
```

Comment: и почему бы в редизайне не сделать метод `clone`?

Comment: @teran Это тоже вариант, но как и все остальные - он тоже в какой-то степени костылен, т.к. легко забыть/перепутать, какие record надо клонировать при присвоении, а какие - нет.

Answer (score 2):

Первый метод:

```
b := Copy(a, 0, MaxInt);
```

Второй метод (при вызове `SetLength` на динамическом массиве, автоматически делается его копия):

```
b := a; 
SetLength(b, Length(a));
```

Comment: Выглядит костыльно, да и забыть легко, *какие* структуры *как* копировать. Напрашивается по крайней мере обернуть это в `b := a.GetCopy` или `b.Assign(a)` и как-то защититься от прямого копирования тогда ..

Comment: @Kromster Ну да, всё надо делать руками. Магического метода глубокого копирования нету.

Comment: В принципе еще есть намеки на то, чтобы как-то прикрутить/использовать RefCount у массива, и если он больше 2, то либо сразу ругаться, либо что-то еще делать. В общем мне нужен код с "защитой от дурака". =)